# Riemann mapping theorem and an inequality inducing conformality

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, conformal-geometry

From an old complex analysis prelim:

> Suppose that $\Omega\not= \mathbb{C}$ is a simply connected region, $a$ and $b$ are distinct points on $\Omega$, $f$ is a conformal map of $\Omega$ on $\mathbb{D}$ with $f(a)=0$, and $g$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$ with $g(\Omega)\subseteq \mathbb{D}$ and $g(b)=0$.
>
> 1. Prove that $|g(a)|\leq |f(b)|$.
> 2. If equality holds, prove that $g$ is a conformal map of $\Omega$ onto $\mathbb{D}$.

I think this has to do with the Riemann mapping theorem, but I don't know how to apply it.  This is a tough problem.

Comment: consider also using the Schwartz lemma

Comment: For $f$ conformal, do you mean $f$ is a bijection from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{D}$? If so, you can use Schwartz lemma for $g\circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: Jerry has given you the key point.  If it still doesn't make sense I can write up an answer tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb D$ is conformal , therefore it is univalent and it has an inverse:
$f^{-1}:\mathbb D\rightarrow \Omega.$

We now need an analytic function $\mathbb D\rightarrow\mathbb D$ which maps $0$ to $0$ in order to use Schwarz's lemma.

First, consider the Möbius Transform of the Disk, $M:\mathbb D\rightarrow\mathbb D,$ which maps $g(a)$ to $0$ and $0$ to $g(a).$ (More precisely, $M(z)= (g(a)-z)/ (1-\overline{g(a)}z).$)

Then the analytic function $M\circ g\circ f^{-1}:\mathbb D\rightarrow \mathbb D$  maps $0$ to $0$, thus , using Schwarz's lemma we obtain :
$$|(M\circ g\circ f^{-1})(z)|\leq|z|\Rightarrow$$
$$|M(g(z))|\leq|f(z)|$$
For $z=b$:
$$|M(g(b))|\leq|f(b)|\Rightarrow |M(0)|\leq |f(b)|\Rightarrow $$
$$|g(a)|\leq|f(b)|$$

Now, if equality holds, then again from Schwarz's lemma :
$$(M\circ g\circ f^{-1})(z)=e^{i\theta}z\Rightarrow$$
$$g(z)=M^{-1}\left(e^{i\theta}f(z)\right)$$ which is conformal, since it is a composition of conformal maps.